# How to Hide and Skip Element of an Array String in Angular 4/6 using Typescript or Html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm implementing a functionality while clicking on the List of Item(Branch) that single Particular Item(Branch) Should be Removed or Just Hide from the (Branch)list and show into another Place as Selected(Branch) and again click on another List of item(Branch List) than Selected(branch) swap that is working fine but the list of Item (Branch list Item ) is not yet removed ??

[   "DevBranch",
    "ProdBranch",
    "UATBranch",
    "SITBranch",
    "QABranch", ]
Given above Item is list of Branches 
and currently selected Branch is ["DevBranch"]
in given below image I have added just for reference NewBranch12 is still in that list

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._branchService.getAllBranch().subscribe(branchList => {
      this.branchList = branchList;
    }, error => this.error = error);
    console.log(this.branchList.length);
    this._branchService.getCurrentBranch().subscribe(currentBranch => {
      this.branchName = currentBranch.slice(34);
    }, error => this.error = error);

    const index: number = this.branchList.indexOf(this.branchName);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.branchList.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

HTML Code

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content  class ="branch">
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <th>Current Branch</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
              <td><b>{{branchName}}</b></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>

  <mat-card-content class ="branch">
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <th>List Of Branches</th>
        </thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let branch of branchList">
          <td><b>{{branch}}</b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image]

Comment: What. Please, keep it simple, give the output your have, and the output you expect. Also, don't post images of your issues/expectations as some people have corporate proxies (and it seems you can avoid using images), and provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably think in this direction:

```
const all$ = this._branchService.getAllBranch();
const current$ = this._branchService.getCurrentBranch();

combineLatest(all$, current$).pipe(
    map(([all, current]) => all.filter(branch => branch !== current))
).subscribe(branchList) => {
    this.branchList = branchList;
})
```